# axios TypeScript confusion - how to access response headers correctly?

Tags: typescript, axios

How do I correctly use the axios-provided TypeScript types to handle errors and get response headers?
In case of 429 (too many requests) my back-end sends a header "retry-after", that I would like to access.
However, the elaborate types are driving me insane.

The following is what I got so far (example is a bit contrived because I simplified my actual code). I let IntelliJ specify some types explicitly.

This is giving an error on the `headers.get(..` line:

`TS2723: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.TS2723: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.`

Huh? Where is `null` or `undefined` coming into play here? How do I do this correctly?

```
    axios
        .post<string>('api/refresh-token', credentials)
        .then(response => {
            const token = response.data;
            console.log("Token", token);
            // ...
        })
        .catch((error: Error | AxiosError) => {
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
                if(error.response) {
                    const response: AxiosResponse<unknown, any> = error.response;
                    const responseStatusCode: number = response.status;
                    if (responseStatusCode == 429) {
                        const headers: RawAxiosResponseHeaders | (RawAxiosResponseHeaders & AxiosHeaders) = response.headers;
                        const retryAfterText: any = headers.get("retry-after");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headers.get` is possibly null here.

The Problem is the very broad definition of the `headers` variable's type.

```
const headers: RawAxiosResponseHeaders | (RawAxiosResponseHeaders & AxiosHeaders) = response.headers;
```

`RawAxiosResponseHeaders` is basically just a plain Object, a union that includes this interface:

```
interface RawAxiosHeaders {
  [key: string]: AxiosHeaderValue;
}
```

And `AxiosHeaderValue` can be among a bunch of other things `null`.

If you tell your IDE that you're expecting the `AxiosHeaders` type the `get` method will definitely not be null.

You could check first if the Object is actually `AxiosHeaders`, then with the correct typing your code should work:

```ts
if (responseStatusCode == 429) {
  const headers = response.headers;
  if (headers instanceof AxiosHeaders) {
    const retryAfterText = headers.get("retry-after");
  }
}
```

The `retryAfterText` variable will then have the type `AxiosHeaderValue`.